What is the difference between calling summary() and train_summary() on a nestcv.train object in the nestedcv package in R?
I am running a series of elastic net models with nested cross validation on my training data, using the nestedcv package in R. I am trying to extract performance metrics to compare models with different feature sets. However, I'm still very unclear on which summary function I should call.
Citing from the package vignette:

Use summary() to see full information from the nested model fitting. (...) For comparison, performance metrics from the left-out inner CV test folds can be viewed using innercv_summary(). Performance metrics on the outer training folds can be viewed with train_summary(), provided the argument outer_train_predict was set to TRUE in the original call to either nestcv.glmnet(), nestcv.train() or outercv().

From this explanation and from the package documentation I don't understand what's the difference between calling summary() and train_summary() on my data. I thought summary() returns performance metrics averaged across the outer training folds, but this explanation makes it seem like that's really what I get from train_summary, and indeed the results are slightly different between the two (see example below). What metrics does summary() return then? And which ones do I want?
#Select features:
features <- mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, disp, vs, am) %>%
  data.matrix()

#Define outcome column:
outcome <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg) %>%
  data.matrix()

#Set model parameters:
myControl <- trainControl(
    method = "repeatedcv",
    number = 5,
    repeats = 5)

#Define tuning grid:
myGrid <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0.1, 0.9, length = 10),
                        lambda = seq(0.1, 0.9, length = 10))

#Tuning both alpha and lambda:
  
set.seed(123, "L'Ecuyer-CMRG") # for reproducibility
fit <- nestcv.train(
  x = features,
  y = outcome[, 1],
  method = "glmnet",
  outer_method = "cv",
  n_outer_folds = 5,
  trControl = myControl,
  tuneGrid = myGrid,
  metric = "RMSE",
  outer_train_predict = TRUE,
)



> summary(fit)
Nested cross-validation with caret
Method:  glmnet 
No filter
Outer loop:  5-fold cv
Inner loop:  5-fold repeatedcv
32 observations, 4 predictors

        alpha  lambda  n.filter
Fold 1    0.1     0.9         4
Fold 2    0.1     0.9         4
Fold 3    0.1     0.9         4
Fold 4    0.1     0.9         4
Fold 5    0.1     0.9         4

Final parameters:
  alpha  lambda
    0.1     0.9

Result:
    RMSE   Rsquared        MAE   
  3.1044     0.7266     2.4648   
> train_summary(fit)
    RMSE   Rsquared        MAE   
  2.7834     0.7833     2.2428 

I have read the package documentation but I still struggle understanding this issue, so a noob-friendly explanation would be greatly appreciated. I also tried manually calculating the metrics from the nestcv.train object but none of my results overlap with either summary() or train_summary() output:
> # mean performance from the outer_result/results table
> df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 0))
> names(df) <- names(fit$outer_result[[1]]$fit$results)
> 
> for(i in 1:2) {
+   new <- fit$outer_result[[i]]$fit$results %>%
+     filter(alpha == fit$outer_result[[i]]$fit$bestTune[[1]],
+            lambda == fit$outer_result[[i]]$fit$bestTune[[2]])
+   df <- bind_rows(df, new)
+ }
> 
> print(mean(df$RMSE, na.rm = T), digits = 4)
[1] 3.323
> 
> 
> # final_fit RMSE
> print(fit$final_fit$results %>%
+         filter(alpha == fit$final_fit$bestTune[[1]],
+                lambda == fit$final_fit$bestTune[[2]]) %>%
+         .$RMSE,
+       digits = 4)
[1] 3.022
> 
> 
> # performance calculated manually: avg. across outer test folds
> metrics_all <- c()
> 
> for(i in 1:2) {
+   pred <- fit$outer_result[[i]]$preds$predy
+   obs <- fit$outer_result[[i]]$preds$testy
+   rmse <- sqrt(mean((pred - obs)^2, na.rm = T))
+   mae <- mean(abs(pred - obs), na.rm = T)
+   rss <- sum((pred - obs)^2, na.rm = T)
+   tss <- sum((obs - mean(obs))^2, na.rm = T)
+   Rsq <- 1 - rss/tss
+   metrics_all <- rbind(metrics_all, c(rmse, Rsq, mae))
+ }
> 
> print(colMeans(metrics_all), digits = 4)
[1] 2.5196 0.8216 2.2331
> 
> # performance calculated manually: avg. across outer train folds
> metrics_all_train <- c()
> 
> for(i in 1:2) {
+   pred <- fit$outer_result[[i]]$train_preds$predy
+   obs <- fit$outer_result[[i]]$train_preds$ytrain
+   rmse <- sqrt(mean((pred - obs)^2, na.rm = T))
+   mae <- mean(abs(pred - obs), na.rm = T)
+   rss <- sum((pred - obs)^2, na.rm = T)
+   tss <- sum((obs - mean(obs))^2, na.rm = T)
+   Rsq <- 1 - rss/tss
+   metrics_all_train  <- rbind(metrics_all_train,  c(rmse, Rsq, mae))
+ }
> 
> print(colMeans(metrics_all_train), digits = 4)
[1] 2.952 0.752 2.351

